# The name 'btn2' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, winforms, sender

Below i put some part of the code the problem is btn2.tag.
it says " The name 'btn2' does not exist in the current context "  how can i fix the issue? what is(are) the way(s)?

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // bla bla bla

        int NumOfButtons = 12;

        int loc = 20; 
        int k = 5;

        for (int i = 1; i <= NumOfButtons; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            {
                lst.Location = new Point(4, 4);
                btn.Size = new Size(55, 55);
                btn.Tag = i;

                command.CommandText = "select product_Name from T_Product where PRODUCT_ID = " + btn.Tag;
                btn.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();  

                btn.Location = new Point(k, loc);
            }


            btn.Click += Buttons_Click;  

    }

    private void Buttons_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        isclicked = true;
        // Used "Sender" to know which button was clicked ?
        Button btn = sender as Button;

        Button btn2 = sender as Button;
        btn2.Tag = btn.Tag;


    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DUK1;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
            command.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();      
            command.CommandText = "select product_PRIZE from T_Product where PRODUCT_ID = " + btn2.Tag;   // here problem occurs

            textBox5.Text = comando.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
```

}

//////

i have some buttons(12) in this example and when i click on the button5 and when i click on the button5, i want to display prize according to the btn2.Tag ( which is one of the 12 button's tag) .

how will i make it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
object tag;
private void Buttons_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    isclicked = true;
    // Used "Sender" to know which button was clicked ?
    Button btn = sender as Button;      
    tag = btn.Tag;
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text != "")
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;
        Initial Catalog=DUK1;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        command.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();      
        command.CommandText = "select product_PRIZE from T_Product where PRODUCT_ID = '" + tag != null ? tag : "" + "'";
        textBox5.Text = comando.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
 }
```

Comment: i am not into the syntax. (its not the full code though but i edited) lets say that we have them how can i take the tag of the button(one the the 12 button) after i click on the button5?

Comment: hey, in the Click event handler for your button5, the `btn2` is obviously not declared in that event handler scope (and it's not a variable declared in the outer scope). You should learn a little about variable scope before programming.

Comment: i'm new bie and learning. im not an expert like you. but if i was an expert i would fix the problem instead of talking and editing like some people do. And your advise is not working also. you mean to Button btn2 = sender as Button; but when i do it its not making what i am asking!

Comment: Mr King its not doing what im asking even when i do  Button btn2 = sender as Button;  lets say i want to take the button1 tag when i clik on button5 which is different then one of the 12 button.

Comment: @modestandcutegirl that's because you expressed your want poorly. I don't really get what you want. What is the button5 for? What about other buttons? I've never worked on a project which used such many buttons for just saving tags?

Comment: Thanks but its not what im wanting. maybe i couldnt explained fine. can you show a msgbox show of an another button tag on the screen when u click to a different button? let say you have 12 button and an another button which is button5 in this case( but its not one of the 12 button its a different button) and when you click on the button5 how can you display the button's tag (which is one of the 12 button)  which is clicked before button5.

Comment: if so, the code I posted should work. The `Buttons_Click` event handler is used for 12 buttons of yours. Any clicking on one of those buttons will save the the Button.Tag (which is clicked) into `tag` variable. And you use that variable in your `button5_Click` event handler.

Comment: Your loop of creating 12 buttons with Location initialized but without `Parent`? So how could you show 12 those buttons?

Comment: yes i think that is what i am asking. ok i thied and worked fine. so what you did was? made  object tag; which should be global variable i think and assigned the btn.tag to this object variable? by making tag = btn.Tag; am i right?

Comment: @modestandcutegirl yes, global variable in your Form class. That kind of work will follow you much if you want to program more.

Comment: i edited the code and added } and said on my first comment on your reply.

Comment: im accepting your answer. ok but beside this people says having global variables is not good so what do u say for that issue in that case. we are using Global object variable.

Comment: and what kind thinsg i can assign to object variable? if i am not sure about the return type etc can i use this object variable also. where can i learn more about these issues? about the sender stuffs and about the object stufs and about the scope stufs? thaks

Comment: @modestandcutegirl you should understand that you are building your own Form class which inherits the `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class, that class can have many members (data members, method members...) as you want if you think they are necessary. `tag` is a data member of your `Form` class. It's just global in that scope. Our computer memory now is increasing every day. You don't need to care much about that problem because it's some kind of `advanced knowledge`. Just learn how to program basically first. and the last I think you are a `procedural programmer` and making familiar with OOP.

Comment: @modestandcutegirl an `object` variable can hold a reference to another variable of any type. I'm not your teacher, it's not very convenient. I think you should Google more and find some basic books on programming... We as programmers always have to learn first before asking for help from others.

Comment: thanks for the info and enlightenment.  i envy those people who knows much about programming i appreciate.

Comment: @modestandcutegirl if you love it, you will surely be expert of course someone reaches the level of an expert soon while someone needs more time. I'm not good at programming but I love it so much and that may be the difference between you and me?

Comment: maybe hope u be a good programmer and i hope i be a good programmer too.